# Installing missing dependencies in an R package

Tags: r, package

I'm distributing an R package that requires other packages. If any are missing I get (for example) the following error:

> library(whSample)
> Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘whSample’ in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]):
> there is no package called ‘dplyr’

I have code to check and install dependencies in the whSample package, but R fails before it gets to it when it sees the `import(dplyr)` in NAMESPACE. Here's the first block of code when the package function is called:

````
  is_installed <- function(mypkg) is.element(mypkg, installed.packages()[,1])
  whInstall <- function(pkgNames){
    for(pkg in pkgNames){
      if(!is_installed(pkg)){
        install.packages(pkg, repos="http://lib.stat.cmu.edu/R/CRAN")
      }
      suppressMessages(suppressWarnings(
        library(pkg, character.only=T, quietly=T, verbose=F)))
    }
  }
  whInstall(c("magrittr","tools","purrr","openxlsx","data.table","dplyr","glue"))```

How can I get R to do these checks without running afoul of NAMESPACE?
````

Comment: is it a package on your internal network, or do you intend to distribute in on CRAN?

Comment: Why are you doing this? If your NAMESPACE file is correct, `install.packages` will install all package dependencies (if they are on CRAN or specified repositories). There is no need for the code you show in a package.

Comment: This currently is for my workplace and is not quite ready for CRAN, although I'd like to put it there when it's sufficiently debugged. The NAMESPACE data was generated from the .R file with the code ```#'@import dplyr``` (and others). Do I need to do more than that?

Comment: No, that will ensure that dplyr will be installed (if it isn't already) when your package is installed. (In general, it's better practice not to import a whole package namespace but only selected functions using `#' @importFrom`.)

Comment: Thanks Roland, but the plot thickens. People (who have no R savvy) are installing the binary (zip) file locally but they get this error when they try to load the library. It all works if I have them install everything first from CRAN. I also use importFrom as much as possible (6 times), but use import for openxlsx, dplyr, and glue since multiple functions are used from them. Should I try to use importFrom for every function in an external package?

Comment: There's a reason the tests for qualifying to post to CRAN are strict :-) .  Follow them and your problems locally will go away.  Avoid  kludge-y workarounds, as they will haunt you forever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you install the package from a local file, install is going to search for dependencies on the same local path... and won't find them.
To get the CRAN dependecies automatically installed, you can use :

```
install.packages("devtools")
devtools::install_local("MypackageName.zip")
```

Answer (score 3):

A short answer is that you can ask people to install with

```r
devtools::install_local("your-package.tar.gz")
```

What's happening behind the scene is that `install.packages` ignores the `dependencies` option when installing from a local file.  It somehow assumes that the repository from which your are installing the package should also have the dependent packages.  But for local files there is no repository, hence no dependency handling occurs.